# Open a form taking a Text field value from a previous form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I found this board and thought I had my answer when a similar question was asked.

I have a form that filters by Area.

The user selects a value from the drop down and it give all Line Numbers in that area the subform.

I would like to use to be able to click on the LineNo in the subform, and have it open form LineListMstr_Entry with a new entry with the LineNo field filled in.

the code I am using is:

```
Private Sub LineNo_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "LineListMstr_Entry", acNormal, , "LineNo = " _
    & [LineListMstr_Entry]![LineNo], acFormEdit, acWindowNormal

End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? You didn't actually ask a question or state that there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something along the lines of,

```
Private Sub LineNo_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "LineListMstr_Entry", DataMode:=acFormAdd, _
                                         OpenArgs:=Me.[LineNo]
End Sub
```

Then in the Form LineListMstr_Entry's On Load event you can have something like.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Me.NewRecord Then _
        Me.LineNo = Me.OpenArgs
End Sub
```